# Stata merge to R merge

Tags: r, merge

I was provided this Stata code:

`DATA MERGEFILE; MERGE SORTED_MRI (IN = A) SORTED_PER (KEEP = ABSHID ABSPID AGECTB SEX IN = B); BY ABSHID ABSPID; RUN`

To simply:
`Merge dataset2 (IN=A) dataset1 (Keep = VariableX, Variable Y, VariableZ, VariableA In=B);  BY VariableX VariableY`

Currently the only R code I know is:

`merge(dataset1, dataset2, by =c("VariableX, VariableY"))`

How do I translate the "Keep" function from the Stata code?

Comment: We need to subset: `dataset2[, c("columnToKeep1", "columnToKeep2", etc)]`

Comment: That is not Stata code. Perhaps SAS. I've removed the Stata tag.